# Why does sorting with PowerShell not reflect in actual folder?

Tags: powershell

I have eight .csv files in **C:\Users\First Last\Documents\Fun Folder**. The files are listed as follows by default:
`a - alpha`
`a - bravo`
`a - charlie`
`a - delta`
`b - alpha`
`b - bravo`
`b - charlie`
`b - delta`

When I sort with PowerShell to pair the files, I run a script at the command line:
`PS C:\Users\First Last\Documents\Fun Folder> ls *.csv | sort {$_.Name[4]}`

Consequently, in the PowerShell window, I see the files sorted in the desired order:
`b - alpha.csv`
`a - alpha.csv`
`a - bravo.csv`
`b - bravo.csv`
`a - charlie.csv`
`b - charlie.csv`
`b - delta.csv`
`a - delta.csv`

However, in the actual folder holding the files, there is no change in the order, and the files are still listed in the default order. Is a fix possible? Thanks.

Comment: You're not renaming the files. So windows doesn't display them any differently. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to sort the files in the desired order so I can run Excel macros on the pairs. For example, I want to run a macro on the `a - alpha` `b - alpha` pair, then the same macro on the `a - bravo` `b - bravo` pair, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

1. The (presumed) ntfs file system orders alphabetically by default.
2. Your command only sorts the **output** of this `Get-ChildItem`.
3. To have the sorting peristent you'll have to rename the files (due to point 1.)

Provided the file names contain only one `space dash space` sequence, this:

```
Get-ChiltItem '* - *.csv' | 
    Rename-Item -NewName {"{0}{1}" -f (($_.BaseName -split ' - ')[1,0] -join ' - '),$_.Extension}
```

will split, reorder and combine the names to persistently rename the files:

```
Name
----
alpha - a.csv
alpha - b.csv
bravo - a.csv
bravo - b.csv
charlie - a.csv
charlie - b.csv
delta - a.csv
delta - b.csv
```

To undo/swap run the script again.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how it works. Imagine a box with a lot of stuff in it. Everybody who looks in it will order the stuff as he pleases. I order them by color and put them back in. Then you order them alphabetical and put them back in. Both changes wont be reflected for the next guy who takes everything out of the box...

One way would be to use `Move-Item` to move them into subfolders according to name.
Another would be to write the Excel macro in a way that it reacts to the secondary name.